# Get Imgur JSON data with URL

Tags: php, curl, imgur

I'm looking at the imgur API and I'm trying to get the imgur JSON data through the following API method:

https://api.imgur.com/models/image

I have already registered my client ID, but have no idea how I would get the JSON data from the URL `https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{id}` (given the ID).

How would I get this data using cURL and PHP?

Here's what I tried, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
function getImageData() {
    $client_id = "<CLIENT_ID>";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/SbBGk');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
    curl_exec($ch);
    $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $lastUrl;
}
```

Comment: I've tried several answers from other stackoverflow questions, but none returned the data I need. I updated the question with what I have now.

Comment: You're not saving the data `$result = curl_exec($ch);` then do `var_dump($result, curl_getinfo());`

Comment: Thanks. That did it. One more question. Given an imgur link (like `https://imgur.com/gallery/s2Bqq` or `https://i.imgur.com/DY1XsA2.jpg`), how would I get the ID of the image (`s2Bqq` and `DY1XsA2`, respectively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the data.

```
function getImageData() {
    $client_id = "<CLIENT_ID>";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/SbBGk');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

To get the id of the image or gallery you need to parse the url with regex. I'm not good with regex, but this should help you. I'm certain there is a better solution to this.

```
preg_match('#(http(s)?:\/\/(www.|i.)?imgur.com)\/(?!a)(gallery\/)?(([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)#i', $link, $matches);
$id = $matches[6];
```